# PHP with sqlite3 support

Tags: php, sqlite

How do I know if PHP is compiled with SQLite support?  If it's not, and I don't have the privileges to change it, what alternatives do I have to read an SQLite database besides access to php-sqlite3 functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you specifically ask for SQLite v.3 support, so what you have to check is `PDO` and `PDO_sqlite` support. The native `php_sqlite` extension only supports SQLite v.2 in PHP 5 to 5.2. PHP 5.3 has a native `php_sqlite3` extension, but I guess this is not your case, as it has been released just yesterday.

I believe you're out of luck if your setup doesn't include that, as the suggested PEAR MDB2 is just an abstraction layer over existing drivers, it does not substitute them.

Answer (score 5):

[`phpinfo();`](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) should tell you what's compiled in. Execute that:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

and look for sqlite within the HTML output.

Answer (score 2):

if you got command line php, do this:

```
php -m
```

SQLite should then be in the list.

If it is not there then I believe your out of luck (but I'am not sure)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have sqllite support built in to php, and cannot build it as an extension, you could always try the pear extension http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2.

I have not used it myself, but it claims to support sqllite http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_sqlite/

Comment: whoops, missed that it was only an abstraction above the sqllite driver, scratch this :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Debian distros

```
apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

or RedHat distros

```
yum install php5-sqlite
```

and make sure sqlite3 is installed